# CSS Override not working

Tags: css, css-specificity

I understand about CSS specificity (a bit), but I can't seem to understand a problem I am currently having.

I have a CSS Reset file, which I include before any other CSS files in my page. This file contains the following

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, menu, time, mark, audio, video {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0 none;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Then, in my own css file (which is added after the reset), I have the following

```
ol, ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

"OL" and "UL" are both single elements in the reset and custom css files - that is, neither of them have any prefix - so I would expect my own css to override the css. For some reason it doesn't.

I have been temporarily appending `!important` to my custom CSS, but I need to do this for almost every rule I am writing.

What am I missing?

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/G8566/

Comment: There has to be something else to it. Everything you posted seems fine. Are you sure the reset isn't called once again after your css?

Comment: for me as well http://jsfiddle.net/5se9k/ there might be some other CSS overwriting or may be some other issue!

Comment: View source in your browser, click on your css files to make sure they exist and in the order you expect.

Comment: Of course, you are all correct. It seems I had a third-party script before the css files, which unknown to me was creating it's own css. The JSFiddle helped me identify that, so thanks